# Questions about using scp

Tags: ubuntu, scp, cp

1. In [a previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/244544/ways-of-file-copy), I asked a
   question about simply right-click
   copy and paste in Nautilus sometimes
   cannot handle files with special
   characters in their names under
   Ubuntu.

   Later I found that scp seems to be
   able to solve this problem. Perhaps
   cp also can, but I haven't been able
   to tried yet.

   So I was wondering in what
   situations scp and cp will fail to
   copy files/directories?
2. If I want to copy all contents under
   directory "source" to be under
   another one "destination", my
   command will be:

   ```
   scp -r source/* user@server:destination
   ```

   I was wondering if I want to copy
   just some not all
   subdiretories/files, i.e. excluding
   other subdirectories and files,
   under "source" to be under
   "destination", how to write a
   command?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have really complex copy/move needs, you may want to strongly consider looking at rsync instead of scp.  It is far more flexible and usable in differing use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

As per the scp man pages:

> scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port]  -S program] **[[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2**

You can keep specifying files at the end there.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `find` to get all files in the current directory and lower:

```
find . > list_of_files
```

Then edit that list_of_files file to just include what you want to copy. Then scp them:

```
for i in `cat list_of_files` ; do scp $i user@server:dest ; done
```